# how to use operator "=" of Equivalent linear

Tags: java

I'm a newbie of programming languages,

how to make a equivalent linear in java

1. i have `3 * a = 15`, if i defined `n = 15`, how i can find `a` value ?
2. i have `2a + 3b = 8`, how i can find `a` and `b` values ?

I tried,

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Linear{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert the value N = ");

    int n = Integer.parseInt(str);

    for (int x=1; x<=10; x++){
      if ((2*x) = n){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("x = ", x); 
      }
    }

  }
}
```

after i compiled it, i get

```
Linear.java:12: error: unexpected type
      if ((2*x) = n){
            ^
  required: variable
  found:    value
1 error
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be `==`.

Comment: Did you mean `==` instead?

Comment: start by learning Java. also understand that '=' and '==' are not the same. '=' is not used in comparison, but in assigning values

Comment: Weirdo, dnsiv, i trying! how do `x` value can run `n / 2` ?

Comment: [Check this answer for your question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51182909/3932762)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `==` to compare 2 values and `=` to assign a variable a value.

So in your case, you should replace

`if ((2*x) = n){`

with

`if ((2*x) == n){`

Comment: i trying, how about my `2` question ?

Comment: Does equation 1 belong to equation 2?
If that's the case, save your value x temporarily, in case it solves your first equation in a particular loop and write a code with your value x as a.

Answer (score 2):

Your line

```
if ((2*x) = n){
```

is wrong. The `=` operator represents an assignment (setting a variable to a given value). The line, as written, is trying to assign the value on the right (`n`) to the "variable" on the left. However, since on the left you have `2*x`, which is not a variable, but an expression, the compiler complains.

You want to *check* for equality, not create an assignment. The correct line is (using `==`):

```
if ((2*x) == n){
```

Comment: i trying, how about my `2` question ?

Answer (score 1):

For question 2 you could simply try with loops for a and b and test the equation:

```
    for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
            if (2 * a + 3 * b == 8) {
                System.out.println("Found solution a = " + a + " and b = " + b);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what the difference `(2 * a + 3 * b == 8)` and `((2 * a) + (3 * b) == 8)` ?

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri `*` has [operator precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) over `+`, so there is no difference. You can use `(2 * a) + (3 * b) == 8` if you think that's more readable, but the code will do the same with or without those parenthesis in this case.